# choice of model n R

Tags: r, statistics

I conducted an analysis in which I analyze unemployment and autocracy. I use for both dependent variable a Fixed Effect model in a panel data from 20 countries over 10 years controlling for country-fixed effects. Furthermore,  unemployment is analyzed as the share of unemployment with values between 0 and 1 (it follows a beta distribution). For the other dependent variable, autocracy is measured as scores which also are values between 0 and 1. In both cases there are not values which are exactly 0 and 1. The problem which I have is if there is a problem that I use Fixed Effects model for these both fractional dependent variable. The other independent variables are continuous and dummies.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a mixed effect model not a fixed effect model?

Comment: I employed at the end a mixed Effect model as you suggested. I just asked if the use of fixed effects model is 'too bad' as using linear regression for a binary dependent variable.